# Remove unwanted lines while Content-Type: text/plain

Tags: php, text, content-type, removing-whitespace

I will describe my problem with code - it would be the best.

```
<?
include('configs.php');  
require_once 'DBQueries.php'; 
$con = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass );
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1250'") or die('Could not set names');     
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
mysql_select_db($db_dbname);     
$oUnexportedOrders = DBQueries::getInstance()->getUnexportedOrders();
header("Content-Type: text/plain");         
while ($aOrderExport = mysql_fetch_assoc ($oUnexportedOrders)){
    echo $aOrderExport['data'];  
}
```

**What is happening:**

1. include some stuff
2. connection to DB
3. get data from DB
4. IMPORTANT: set header as Content-Type: text/plain
5. IMPORTANT: print text data with echo

**Result:**

```
**!!! There are 7 unwanted lines !!!**
line of data
line of data 
line of data
line of data
....
```

**Expected result:**

```
line of data
line of data 
line of data
line of data
```

**- Expected is lines of data generated by echo inside the for, but without that 7 lines.**

**QUESTION:**

How to do that, what to call when (etc.) to get rid of those unwanted lines?

Thank you.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I know this, but Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ob_clean();` will clear out the output buffer, in conjuction with `ob_start();`

```
<?
ob_start();
include('configs.php');  
require_once 'DBQueries.php'; 
$con = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass );
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1250'") or die('Could not set names');     
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
mysql_select_db($db_dbname);     
$oUnexportedOrders = DBQueries::getInstance()->getUnexportedOrders();
ob_clean();
header("Content-Type: text/plain");         
while ($aOrderExport = mysql_fetch_assoc ($oUnexportedOrders)){
    echo $aOrderExport['data'];  
}
```

That should get rid of any unwanted extra whitespace from included files.

Comment: I think it also would be a good idea to explain why this is happening.

Comment: well from http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php it is quite obvious: quote: "While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer."

Answer (score 0):

The blank lines don't come from the mysterious unknown. They're in your code somewhere. Check your files (including the files you include/require) for whitespace before your opening PHP tags and after your closing PHP tags. That whitespace will be passed to the browser.